# How do I get a JAX-WS operation to default to UTF-8 under JBoss 6.2

Tags: jboss, character-encoding, jax-ws

I have a client application that expects web service requests and responses to be UTF-8, though it does not explicitly specify that in the request.  I'm porting the service implementation from a CGI application under IIS 6, to a java implementation using JAX-WS running on JBoss.  When the request arrives it is treated as an ISO-8859-1 encoded request and the response is encoded as ISO-8859-1.

The solution seems simple... tell JAX-WS (or JBoss) to assume UTF-8 rather than ISO-8859-1, but, so far I've not been able to identify a way of accomplishing this.

How do I tell JAX-WS (or JBoss) to default to UTF-8 rather than ISO-8859-1?